# Check all the visible textboxes on a page should have a value JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to check if a text box is visible then the user should enter a value in it.
the below piece doesn't work.

```
if ($(':text.TextNormalJQH').is(':visible').filter('[value=""]').length > 0) 
  {
     alert (" Entering data for all the visbile textboxes is mandatory");
  }
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close.  Just change it to:

```
if ($(':text.TextNormalJQH:visible').filter('[value=""]').length > 0) {
  alert (" Entering data for all the visbile textboxes is mandatory");
}
```

Or, you could do this:

```
if ($(':text.TextNormalJQH:visible').is('[value=""]')) {
  alert (" Entering data for all the visbile textboxes is mandatory");
}
```

The reason you're having problems is your use of `.is()`.  Basically, it returns true if any of the matched items pass it, filter returns the matched items. http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a .each(), because that's a result set (you have more than one text input on the page), so the following might work

```
var isOk = true;
$(':text.TextNormalJQH').each(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':visible') && $(this).val().length == 0))
        isOk =  false;
}) 

if(!isOk)
{
     alert (" Entering data for all the visbile textboxes is mandatory");
}
```

Comment: $.each loop is very inefficient, and unnecessary in this case.  He's just got his selectors wrong.

Comment: hm, didn't think of it that way.. i guess yours is shorter